# Thread.Join not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a small example using join method and `Thread.sleep`, but I am confused how the flow works.

Here is my program:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    private String msg;
    private int seconds;

    public Reminder(int sec, String msg) {
        this.sec= sec;
        this.msg= msg;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sec* 1000);
            System.out.print(msg+ " ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Test(1, "one"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Test(3, "two"));

        t2.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.join();
        t1.join();      
    }
}
```

Since I am calling `t2.join()`, the `t2` thread should complete before `t1` thread completes.

So I am expecting output as `two one`, but I am getting output as `one two`

Comment: Why are you expecting that? Join just means "wait till it's done", doesn't mean "other threads can't run before this one is done". If you want ordering, you'll have to impose it.

Comment: t1 completes before t2 (1 second instead of 3 for t2)

Comment: t2.join is not going to block the already started thread t1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since I am calling t2.join(), the t2 thread should complete before t1
>   thread completes.

This is not correct , join will not guarantee which thread will finish first , the two threads started so no guarantee which one will finish first, join will block the main thread until the thread finishes, so basically all you are doing with join is you are blocking main thread from waiting the next thread to finish which may already finished.

if you want t1 to start after t2 finishes then you need to call start after t2 finishes and here you can use join

```
 t2.start();
 t2.join();//main thread will stop here untill t2 is finished 
 t1.start()
```

This is actually not practical since no real difference between it and doing your tasks in one thread, just the overhead of creating threads

Answer (score 2):

> Since I am calling t2.join(), the t2 thread should complete before t1 thread completes.

Not at all. You wait for t2 to end - but that doesn't prevent the other thread from progressing.

So only the *first* part of your assumption is correct. That code waits for t2 to complete. That doesn't have **any** effects on the "completeness" of t1.

Assume you have two runners, starting at the same point in time. You sit at the finish line, and you only observe the slower runner. Now the slower runner passes the finish line. Why would you expect the *faster* runner to still be running? He made it to the finish line whilst you were only looking at the slower guy!

Answer (score 1):

> Since I am calling t2.join(), the t2 thread should complete before t1
>   thread completes.

It is not the case if `t1` that is started first has terminated its execution before

`t2.join();` is executed.

To allow `t2` to be completed before `t1`, start `t2`, invoke `join()` on it.
 Then start `t1`:

```
t2.start();
t2.join();
t1.start();
```

But it defeats in a some way multi threading as each thread is started only as the previous is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The threads are starting to run rightaway after you call start(). This inclused the writeln().

join() merely collects some resources from the thread, blocking until the thread is done in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Join method makes the main thread wait for the other thread to complete executing before it can carry out the next code after the join function call.

This has nothing to do with the interrelationship between two or more threads that you spawn.